# Rear brake rubs against the tire

Tags: tire, brakes

I just had my rear tire replaced at an -- admittedly shady -- bike shop, and now the upper part of the rear brake is rubbing against the lower part of the tire:

[image: rear brake]

The yellow dust on the picture results from the friction between the tire and the brake.

However, the wheel is the same as before replacing the tire and the axis seems to be correctly centered:[image]

Brakes are lowered as low as possible. I'm really at a loss here, so I'll be happy to hear any suggestion.

Comment: The new tire is probably slightly fatter than your old one.  Or maybe you just didn't notice the problem with the old one because it had black sidewalls.  Generally the brake pads can be rotated up/down slightly due to a curved washer.  A very slight downward rotation should be all that's necessary.  In a pinch you can shave off the top corners of the pads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out it had nothing to do with changing the tire: the brakes were simply worn out. Solved by replacing the brakes.